# Why RuntimeWarning encountered is dependent on the position of variables?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In the following code I receive a message that "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log". I know that this message appears when log values a are two small. But why it is dependent on the position of the variable? Like in the following code while defining s if I use np.log((Q[j])/np.log(P[j])) i get error but if I replace the numerator with denominator the message diappers. Why is it so?

```
`Q= np.array([0., 0., 2.02575004])
P=np.array([0.90014722, 0.93548378, 0.92370304])
for i in range(len(Spectrum_bins)):
    for j in range(len(P)):
        if Q[j] !=0:
            s= (P[j])*np.log((Q[j])/np.log(P[j]))
            print(s)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because the values of P are all below 1 then the value of np.log(P[j]) is negative. It is not mathematically possible to find the log of a negative number so numpy returns nan (Not a Number).
This is where the first error comes from.

To address your second question, I assume you are changing the equation to

```
np.log(np.log(P[j])/np.log(P[j]))
```

which would result in the natural log of 1, which equals 0. This is a real number and so no error would be returned.

Comment: In order to overcome this error should I implement condition if Q[j]>1 and P[J]>1: ? Because In this case I only consider positive values.

Comment: @jerry i'm not sure exactly what you need to achieve, but to only return real values then the conditions should be Q[j] > 0 & P[j] > 1

Comment: I want to make sure that in order to overcome above mentioned warning Q[j] >1 and P[j]>1 is the only condition that we need to implement.

Comment: Yep that will prevent any negative values for s